# Alloy pred/fun parameter constraint

Tags: alloy

The following Alloy predicate p has a parameter t declared as a singleton of type S.  Invoke `run p` gives the correct result because the predicate body states that t may contain two different elements `s` and `s'`.  However, in the second `run` command, a set of two disjoint elements of type `S` is passed into predicate `p` and this command gives an instance.  Why is it the case?

```
sig S {}

pred p(t: one S) {
  some s, s': t | s != s'
}

r1: run p -- no instance found

r2: run { -- instance found
  some disj s0, s1: S {
    S = s0 + s1
    p[S]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43002442/1547046. Same issue, I think.

BTW, there's a nice research problem here. Can you define a coherent semantics for argument declarations that would be better (that is, simpler, unsurprising, and well defined in all contexts)?